# Unique constraint on multiple fields in Doctrine MongoDB ODM in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have found Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique but it seems to be valid only for one field (found in this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/form.html as class annotation).
Is there any simple solution for such validation on more than one field?

Comment: Have you tried just adding the @MongoDBUnique annotation to the field instead of the class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but i`ve found simple solution - just add more than one @MongoDBUnique constraint works. Remember to separate @MongoDBUnique for each unique field, nor combining all fields into array as in @UniqueEntity. –